# get Style settings from each cell in PHPOffice/PhpSpreadsheet

Tags: php, excel, phpexcel, phpspreadsheet

I am working on a PHP project using the PHPOffice/PhpSpreadsheet library.
I want to place a entire worksheet in an HTML table. That works, but I'm trying to find a way to read the settings for each cell like the number of decimals. Some cells shows decimals, while the cell has been set to zero decimals in the cell properties in the real Excel application.

Also the date has been shown as a number. I know how to convert it but my application does not know which cell is a date. (There is just one date cell in the entire worksheet that I would like to recognize as a date-number). Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why don't you take a look at how the HTML Writer works? Or even use the HTML Writer itself?

Comment: But as a simplistic approach, look at the cell's `getFormattedValue()` method

Comment: getFormattedValue() gives the value but not with the exact number of decimals and other format options. @Mark: Thanks i did not see this HTML writer before. Unfortunately the writer gives the same result.

Comment: `getFormattedValue()` uses the number format mask that is set for the cell, which should include the correct number of decimals to use.... so what is the number format mask for the cell, how many decimals should it be displaying according to that mask, and how many is it displaying?

Comment: You can check the number format mask for a cell using `$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
        ->getStyle('C9')
        ->getNumberFormat()
        ->getFormatCode();`

Comment: And by other format options, do yo mean things like colour, alignment, underlining, etc? the `getStyle()` call returns an object with all these details; if a cell contains rich text, then the cell value is a rich text object rather than a simple scalar value

Comment: $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet() ->getStyle('C9') ->getNumberFormat() ->getFormatCode(); gives "General" in every case.

Comment: Are you loading the file with `$objReader->setReadDataOnly(true);`?

Comment: That is right Mark.

Comment: Then you're telling PHPExcel to load only the raw cell data values, and not to load any style information at all.... remove that one line, and then look at the cell styles, getFormattedValue() and the HTML Writer

Comment: [For reference](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/blob/1.8/Documentation/markdown/ReadingSpreadsheetFiles/05-Reader-Options.md#reading-only-data-from-a-spreadsheet-file)

Comment: That was the trick :-) Thank you very much Mark. If you want you can  add the answer and i will vote .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had to remove this sentence:

```
$objReader->setReadDataOnly(true);
```

So that all the data would be read from the spreadsheet.